# Plotting Phase Diagram

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have the following problem that I'm sure *Mathematica* can handle, but it's not working for me!

In the following code, I'm trying to replicate the Ramsey Model Phase Diagram.

[image: Ramsey Model Phase Diagram]

In fact, I want now to be able to dram the stable arm of the system. My attempted is using `NDSolve`, since I cannot do better. The idea is given a $z_0$ in the regions where exist a stable arm (the ones where the blue line cuts). I tried the framework of BV problems and add up some 1% range; I'm rather sure *Mathematica* can do better than this.

Could anybody suggest me a way to solve it, because `NDSolve` refuses to work with this coding, and I really don't know how to do it.

```
α = 0.3;
ρ = 0.02;
θ = 2;
η = 0.5;
δ = 0.05;
A = 1.0;

T = 600;
err = 0.01;
{zM, cM} = {250000, 1000};

Dz = A α^α η^η (α+η)^-(α+η) z^(α+η)-δ z- c;
Dc = θ^-1 (A α^α η^η (α+η)^(1-(α+η))  z^(α+η-1) - ρ-δ); 
{zT, cT} = NSolve[{Dc == 0, Dz == 0}, {z, c}][[1, All, 2]]

Plot1 = ContourPlot[{Dz==0,Dc==0},
   {z, 0, zM}, {c, 0, cM},
   PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
   PlotLegends -> {"Subscript[Overscript[z, .], t]=0", "Subscript[Overscript[c, .], t]=0"}, 
   Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"z", "c"},
   PlotRange -> {{0, zM}, {0, cM}}, ImageSize -> Large
 ];

z0 = 10000;

sol=NDSolve[
     {z'[t] == A α^α η^η (α+η)^-(α+η) z[t]^(α+η)- δ z[t]- c[t],
      c'[t] == c[t]/θ (A α^α η^η (α+η)^(1-(α+η)) z[t]^(α+η-1) - ρ-δ),
      Abs[z[T]-zT]<err*zM,
      Abs[c[T]-cT]<err*cM
     },
     {z, c}, {t, 0, T},
     Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {z[0] == z0}}
    ];

Plot2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{z[t], c[t]} /.sol], {t,0,T},
          PlotRange -> {{0, zM}, {0, cM}}, ImageSize -> Large
        ];

Show[{Plot1, Plot2}]
```

Comment: This is pretty much a code dump. Could you at least remove the useless formatting in your plots, reduce the code down to a minimal example, indicate what happens when you try to run `NDSolve`, whether you get an error etc. Why should we do all that for you?

Comment: What do you mean by "stable arm of the system"?

Comment: You can ameliorate my solution by adding to ContourPlot  PlotPoints -> 50.

Comment: When I export in eps that graphic seems perfect. The problem is only with png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am badly placed to critic you question since I use to be as criptic as you. First only an economist can understand your objective since this representation is not so standard as you think. I have tried a day long to change the parameters but it is nearly impossible to change the position of c=0. Using the free add-on of Gianluca Gorni here is the best I have been able to do --- I have changed the font to times since I guess you are typesetting with Tex.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
Needs["CurvesGraphics6`"];
ClearAll[α, ρ, θ, η, δ, A, z, c, t];
α = 0.3;
ρ = 0.001;
θ = 2.;
η = 0.09;
δ = 0.05;
 A = 1;
 Φ = 
  A α^α η^η (α + η)^-(α + \
 η);
Ω = 
 A α^α η^η (α + η)^(
 1 - (α + η));
{zM, cM} = {250., 1.}
F[z_, c_] := Φ z^(α + η) - δ z - c
G[z_, c_] := 
1/θ (Ω z^((α + η) - 
  1)) - (ρ + δ)
NSolve[Φ z^(α + η) - δ z == 0, z]
NSolve[1/θ (Ω z^((α + η) - 
   1)) - (ρ + δ) == 0, z]
 sol1 = NDSolve[( {
 {z'[t] == Φ z[t]^(α + η) - δ z[
      t] - c[t]},
 {c'[t] == 
   1/θ (Ω z[t]^((α + η) - 
        1)) - (ρ + δ)},
 {z[0] == 5},
 {c[0] == 1.5}
} ), {z, c}, {t, 0, 800}, PlotSolution -> True, 
ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotPoints -> 50];
sol2 = NDSolve[( {
 {z'[t] == Φ z[t]^(α + η) - δ z[
      t] - c[t]},
 {c'[t] == 
   1/θ (Ω z[t]^((α + η) - 
        1)) - (ρ + δ)},
 {z[0] == 15.6342},
 {c[0] == 2}
} ), {z, c}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotSolution -> True, 
ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"];
sol3 = NDSolve[( {
 {z'[t] == Φ z[t]^(α + η) - δ z[
      t] - c[t]},
 {c'[t] == 
   1/θ (Ω z[t]^((α + η) - 
        1)) - (ρ + δ)},
 {z[0] == 20},
 {c[0] == 1.2}
 } ), {z, c}, {t, 0, 30}, PlotSolution -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"];
sol4 = NDSolve[( {
 {z'[t] == Φ z[t]^(α + η) - δ z[
      t] - c[t]},
 {c'[t] == 
   1/θ (Ω z[t]^((α + η) - 
        1)) - (ρ + δ)},
 {z[0] == 0.429975},
 {c[0] == .2}
} ), {z, c}, {t, 0, 80}, PlotSolution -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"];
 p = ContourPlot[{F[z, c] == 0, G[z, c] == 0}, {z, 0, 80}, {c, 0, 2.}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.75, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
 PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(t\)]\)=0", 
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(c\), \(t\)]\)=0"}, Frame -> False, 
  Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(t\)]\)", 
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(c\), \(t\)]\)"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times"], 
  ContourStyle -> {Red, Green}];
SetOptions[Show, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14},
Ticks -> None];
Show[p, sol1[[2]], sol2[[2]], sol3[[2]], sol4[[2]], 
Graphics[{PointSize[0.025], Point[{20, 1.2}, VertexColors -> Blue], 
Point[{15.6342, 2}, VertexColors -> Blue], 
Point[{5, 1.5}, VertexColors -> Blue], 
Point[{0.429975, .2}, VertexColors -> Blue], 
Point[{6.35, 1.355}, VertexColors -> Red]}], 
Graphics[Text[
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(c\), \(.\)], \(t\)]\)=0", {12, 
1.05}]], 
Graphics[Text[
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(z\), \(.\)], \(t\)]\)=0", {65, 
1.05}]], BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, 
Ticks -> None]
```

I think that most representations in text books do not emphazises enough on the difficulty of the graphic representations due to numerical problems. One remarks --- I do not know why the graphic her is not exactly the one shown in mathematica --- no labels, no adapted fonts.

A last thing. I have not tried to put the arrows  because the graphic could be unreadable.

Nevertheless, if you have difficulties with the code send me a message I will send it to you by mail.

Comment: Wow. This looks amazing. In fact, my gf is an economist and was asking to help her. Thank you very much.

Comment: Dear Guilherme, if you think the answer usefull marks it . I have been scold because I was unaware of the good comportment on stack exchange. Drive you mouse on the triangles at the beginning of the answer you will understand.

Comment: Of course, I was going to upvote it! Cheers!

Comment: Dear, @cyrille.piatecki, I found you answer very nice. But there's a point I don't get: how did you get the values of z[0] and c[0] that were in the stable path (sol2 and sol4)?